# Vim file explorer with random multiple roots

Tags: vim

One thing I like about [Sublime Text](http://www.sublimetext.com/) is that you can drag any folder in the left panel and this folder can be expanded independently from the others. How can I achieve the same functionality in Vim?

I'm currently using NERDTree which currently supports a single root. When you open another folder it replaces the current hierarchy. So I wouldn't mind dropping this plugin in favor of another solution.

Comment: No, such a thing doesn't exist.

Comment: follow @romainl's comment:  because vim user doesn't have a mouse... :P

Comment: @Kent, I don't care about the drag & drop. I might as well type :e /some/folder and have it added to the panel. Anyway it's not the end of the world, I can probably live without this.

Comment: Yes. You can certainly live without all the pointless eye candy (you probably got used to) in ST2. It will require a change of mind, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It took me a while, but I managed to work something out.
I made it into a separate plugin: [Vimpanel](http://mihaifm.github.com/vimpanel/)

I put a lot of other usefull things in there, apart from the "killer feature" of being able to have multiple roots.

Answer (score 3):

The *netrw* plugin that ships with Vim allows to open multiple, different splits to different locations, e.g. vertically with `:Vexplore`.

To make it show a recursive tree, use:

```
:let g:netrw_liststyle=3
```

Comment: This will work, obviously. I wonder if the OP will mark this as an answer since it's quite far from his "sublime" experience.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know any plugin that does this, but from my brief forays into NERDTree's source code, I know that modifying the plugin to do what you want is not out of the question. It would involve delving into the logic and modifying / commenting out the parts that search and re-use the current NERDTree buffer. If you're familiar with Vimscript, not a huge challenge. (Maybe you could even introduce a configuration setting for it and send it to the author for inclusion.)

Comment: yea, this is probably the way to go. I actually added a [feature request](https://github.com/scrooloose/nerdtree/issues/215) for it, but I guess I could get my hands dirty and look into it myself.